# Android Studio Date compare from GetCurrentMillis

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, timestamp

I've created an android-application to register visitors currently visiting our company, by allowing them to check-in and check-out. When checking in, I store the information and the GetCurrentMillis in a SQLite database. I would like to add two features but I can't get it to work properly:

- When visitors forget to check-out, their info remains in the database. I need a query that checks out all visitors where the date in the check-in Timestamp != today.
- Information will only be stored for 14 days, so I need a query that deletes all visitors where the date in the check-in Timestamp < 14 days ago.

I might need to modify the GetTimeMillis, because I don't need the milliseconds. 
What would be the SQLite queries for both of them?

Added: My attempts at both of the queries (thanks @Cid for reminding):

```
String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME;
    query += " SET " + COL_5 + " = '" + outTime + "'";
    query += " WHERE (" + COL_5 + " IS NULL";
    query += " OR " + COL_5 + " = '')";
    query += " AND date(" + COL_4 + ") < ' + date('now') + '";
    db.execSQL(query);
```

And:

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    query += " WHERE " + COL_5 + " IS NOT NULL";
    query += " AND date(" + COL_4 + ") <= date('now', '-14 day')";
    db.execSQL(query);
```

Comment: Checking out the 'expired' visitors in this case means to add the date of the starttime column + 23.59.59 to the endtime column

Comment: *I need a query that [...]*. Do it then. Or if you did it, show us the query that has issues.

Comment: @Cid I added my attempts

Comment: `" AND date(" + COL_4 + ") < ' + date('now') + '";` Looks like you forgot double quotes. Do you meant : `" AND date(" + COL_4 + ") < '" + date('now') + "'";` ? Same for the second query

Comment: The date('now') function is a SQLite function, not a Java function, so this part should be within the string. Adding the quotes results in an error on date('now') (Too many characters in character literal)

Comment: Then, the `+` characters are maybe in excess